# bounded solutions of linear system of differential equations based on eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a system of differential equations given by,
$$\frac{dX}{dt}=AX,$$
where $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$), and where $A$ is a (constant) $n \times n$ matrix with real entries. I have such a system in my research, and essentially I want to tinker with the entries of $A$ so that the solutions are all bounded - in the sense that the set $\{X(t), t \geq 0\}$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for any solution $X(t)$.

For the solution paths to be bounded, is it sufficient that the (pure-real or complex) eigenvalues of $A$ have non-positive real parts? I *think* this is true, but am not quite sure from my reading.

Thank you!

Comment: Is $A$ a constant matrix?

Comment: it is, I'll edit my question shortly

Answer (score 1):

If $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end {pmatrix}$, then $X=\begin{pmatrix} t\\ 1 \end {pmatrix}$ is a solution that grows linearly with t.  If there are no degenerate eigenvalues with $0$ real parts then this cannot happen.  More generally, if $A$ is reduced  to Jordan canonical form and there are no non-zero entries above the eigenvalues with $0$ real parts and there are no eigenvalues with positive real parts then all solutions are bounded.